# Can I do this with a single loop?

Tags: php

I have an array of "striuctures", let's say each lookss like

```
$a['field_1'] = 'value 1';
$b['field_1'] = 'value 2';
$c['field_1'] = 'value 3';
```

and I store it in a MySql database.

Then later, I want to make a comparission against an array $b, which has the same keys and I want to ask

```
for each $a
   is there a $a['field_1'] where 'value X' == the value of $b['field_1'] ?
```

Can I avoid

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++)       
  for ($j = 0; $j < count($b); $j++)     
     if ($a[$i]['field_1'] == $b[$j]['field_1'])  
         &hellip;
```

I would also like to do it in reverse.

Is there any built-in function which I am overloooking, or must I go with two loops?

(btw, I am not using `foreach` because I want to pass $a by reference into a function and that gave me problems with `foreach` but not with a for loop -- for some reason which I can't fathom)

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question, you want to compare 2 arrays with one another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($a as $i => $val) {
    if(in_array($val, $b)) {
         doSomething($a, $i);
    }
}
```

If you need the location in B too, use this:

```
foreach($a as $i => $val) {
    $j = array_search($val, $b)
    if($j !== FALSE) { // note operator MUST be !==
         doSomething($a, $i, $b, $j);
    }
}
```

I should warn you it's just concealing the second loop, but it may be optimized this way.

Also, I used the `foreach`, because it should work fine the way I have it here.  Feel free to change it back if necessary.

Comment: I understand that it's conceling th esecond loop. I was thinking more of legible code. Thanks

Comment: I just though of a different method.  If you just need a list of values that are in borg arrays, try using array_intersect: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Answer (score 1):

You can check that in MySQL using a query similar to this:

```
mysql_query('SELECT id FROM table WHERE field_1="' . $b['field_1'] . '";');
```

Comment: This would require him to make a single query for EVERY SINGLE ELEMENT, which isn't very effective.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

    $array1 = array("value1", "value2", "value3");
    $array2 = array("value1", "value2", "value3");

    if (empty(array_diff($array1,$array2))) {
        echo "Arrays are equal!";
    }
    else echo "Arrays are NOT equal!";

?>
```